# Make events run multiple times, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highchart in which under the `options` object I have events object as ashown below.

```
  var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10,
                    events: {
                        load: function() {

                            var series = this.series[0],
                                chart = this;

                    ...// Some Code
                   }
                 }
```

So what I want is that I need `events` data to update dynamically and load the Highcharts only once.

How can I make the Following section dynamic so that the values in it change dynamically. Keeping in mind that Highcharts container have to be defined and load only once.

```
events: {
           load: function() {
            var series = this.series[0],
                                chart = this;
                    ...// Some Code
                   }
                 }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the official Highcharts demos shows how to achieve it. Take a look at it:

```
setInterval(function () {
var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        y = Math.random();
    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
}, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

Highcharts also offers other options to update the chart with new data, API:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData